# Data Structure for Multi-Level Traversal

Tags: algorithm, oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, linked-list

I have an application that deals with data in the following structure:

```
struct Message
{
   int    time;
   string name;
   string details;
};
```

For example, I may have a data set that looks like the following:

```
9:00:00 Bob  <Info>
9:01:00 John <Info>
9:05:00 Bob  <Info>
9:11:00 Mary <Info>
9:17:00 John <Info>
9:25:00 Mary <Info>
9:30:00 Bob  <Info>
```

And I will have a list of `Message` structures that represent each line in the data set.

Some operations I will need to do on this data include:

- Collect all data in chronological order and `dostuff()`
- Collect all data from `John` (or whoever) in chronological order and `dostuff()`

So, I need a way to traverse the list such that I can pass every message in chronological order, and also choose a person, and pass through only their messages in chronological order.

My thoughts are to have a struct like this:

```
struct Node
{
   Message* message;
   Node*    next_time;
   Node*    next_name;
};
```

In which `next_time` points to the next `Node` in chronological order, and `next_name` points to the next `Node` that belongs to `message->name`.  And a `Root` structure points to the first of each type.

```
struct Root 
{
   Node* first_time;
   Node* first_bob;
   Node* first_john;
   Node* first_mary;

   Node* last_time;
   Node* last_bob;
   Node* last_john;
   Node* last_mary;
};
```

Here is an image to illustrate the point.

[image]

This structure allows me to fairly easily traverse through every message, or through only Bob's messages, or only John's, etc.

However, I am worried that maybe this is more complicated than it needs to be.  I also have concerns about maintenance (see below).  I need the search/select/read operations to be pretty fast, which I think they are.  And I need insert operations to be reasonably fast.  But right now, for every `Message` I insert, I must (1) update some `next_time` pointer and (2) update some `next_name` pointer.

My question is:
Does a data structure exist that provides this type of functionality already?  If not, am I approaching this problem correctly?

Please provide any code samples in C++ or C#, if possible.

Thanks.

Additional: Suppose later I want to add to my `Message` struct.  Let's say I add a field called `City`.  Now, I may want to do this:

- Collect all data from a specific `City` in chronological order and `dostuff()`

This would require adding a `next_city`, and then for every insert, I would have to update `next_time`, `next_name`, AND `next_city`.

Further, suppose I want to do this:

- Collect all data from a specific `City` AND a specific `name` in chronological order and `dostuff()`

I think this makes the problem incredibly more difficult unless I opt to traverse every `Message` and skip the ones I don't care about.

Comment: How many different users will there be? If the number is small, you can probably get away with just skipping over messages you aren't interested in.

Comment: @takteek: I thought about that -- The number of people/users/names is arbitrary, and will be somewhat small, but the number of `Messages` for each person will be very large.  It's possible I'll end up skipping tons of `Messages`

Comment: Do you need efficient random insertion or just appending?

Comment: @Thom Smith: Probably 99% of the time will be appending. With that said, I will definitely keep a pointer to the last message -- I think that is what you were getting at.

Comment: @user807566 how can you just append if your messages must be in chrono order?

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Most of the time the `Messages` will be loaded chronologically (from some external file).  I'll do a check to make sure they're being inserted in the correct place, but almost every time they *should* be added to the end.

Comment: @user807566 So do you still have any problems?

Comment: @Steh Carnegie: What do you mean? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @user807566 sorry, I was just asking if you had solved your problem, it seemed you had.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Oh, sorry. No, I have not solved it. I haven't started the code yet - I wanted to get some other opinions first before committing to a specific architecture.

Comment: If you haven't looked at it, Boost [Multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) seems like the obvious choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple linked list of all messages (sorted by time).

```
struct Node
{
   Message* message;
   Node*    next_name;
};
```

This will satisfy req 1. You can add() and getAll() in O(1)

A separate hashmap with User as key and a list of Node* as values.

```
Hashmap
{key = User, value = List(Message*)}
```

This will satisfy req 2. You can add a new entry to the end of the list of the specific user O(1) and getAllOfUser() can also run in O(1)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a class to represent a user, storing users in an hash table by some identifier like the name, then have each user hold a list of `Message`s sorted in chronological order, which are also stored in a single global list which holds everyone's `Message`s in chronological order. For every added `Message`, you'd have to insert it once in each list (by list I mean some collection), which could be `log n` time, or as bad as `n`, depending on the data structure.